# How to Continue this After finding the Integrating Factor?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about differential equations. I want to find the general solution to the following equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy=\ln x, y(1)=1$

I wish to use the integrating factor method to solve it. This is already in the standard form. So, I calculated the integrating factor, and it is $e^{-2x^2}$. Then, I used the general solution formula to get $y(t)=Ce^{2x^2}+e^{2x^2} \int e^{-2x^2}g(t)dt$, where $g(t)=y'(t)+p(t)y(t)$. $pt(t)$ is just the integrating factor. What to do next?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a solution in terms of elementary functions as [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-x%5E2%29ln%28x%29) points out.

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform gives the answer in terms of hypergeometric functions:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2-1}\left(-2ex\,_2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)+2e\,_2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-1\right)+e\sqrt{\pi}\,\text{erf}(x)\log(x)+2\right).$$

Comment: The integrating factor is $e^{-x^2}$, the factor $2$ gets consumed in the integration of the monomial. Can you check that there was no leading factor $x^2$ that got lost, because then this DE would be more simple to handle as Euler-Cauchy type DE?